# how can I look up objective-c's property @synthesize getter setter code

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

in interview has a question "Could NSMutableArray property use copy why and why not " I have searched the answer but I want to see the auto generate's getter setter code how can I do?

Comment: `copy` returns an immutable `NSArray`. `mutableCopy` would return a copied `NSMutableArray`. By declaring the property as `copy`, you can access the elements but you won't be able to mutate the internal structure without calling the setter explicitly. Basically it's the exact reason why we have `copy` properties. Technically, all `NSMutableArray` properties should be `copy` unless your design is bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot see the Obj-C code for the setter only the assembler. To do this first select the source file containing the property in Xcode and then choose the menu item `Produce > Perform Action > Assemble "File.m"`. This will open up a window containing the assembly code. Search for `setPropertyName:` where `PropertyName` is the capitalised name of your property.

This will show you the setter calls `_objc_setProperty_nonatomic_copy` or `_objc_setProperty_atomic_copy`. To see the code for those you will need to use the debugger and step into them. They essentially just call `copyWithZone:`.

More important is the reason behind the interview question. Either simple experimentation, or digging through the assembler as above, shows that the `copy` property attribute always does a `copy` and not a `mutableCopy`. So the declaration:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *shouldBeInvalid;
```

would in an ideal world generate a compiler error. If you assign a mutable array value to the property:

```
self.shouldBeInvalid = @[ @24 ].mutableCopy;
```

then due to the `copy` the value actually assigned is an *immutable* array (`NSArray`), contradicting the `NSMutableArray` declared type. Trying to use the property value later as a mutable array:

```
[self.shouldBeInvalid addObject:@42];
```

will produce a runtime error as the property's value is an immutable object contrary to its declared type...

You'll also find that the compiler happily allows you to assign an immutable array to the property:

```
self.shouldBeInvalid = @[ @24 ];
```

without so much as a warning.

What the interviewer was probably seeking was for you to explain that for a property `copy` + mutable type makes no sense in Objective-C as the copy will produce an immutable object value. However a property with `copy` and an immutable object type (`NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, etc.) does make sense so that if a mutable object value is assigned an immutable copy of it is made, which prevents the property's value changing unexpectedly, e.g.:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *shouldHaveCopy;

NSMutableArray *sample = @[ @"oops" ].mutableCopy;

self.shouldHaveCopy = sample;

[sample addObject:@"'immutable' property changed"];

// self.shouldHaveCopy now references a two element array despite
// its type being `NSArray`
```

So the general rules are:

- A property intended to have a mutable object value (`NSMutableDictionary` *et al*) should never specify `copy`; and
- A property intended to have an immutable object value, when there is a corresponding mutable object subclass (e.g. `NSArray` has `NSMutableArray` etc.), should always specify `copy`.

HTH

Comment: when I perform this "Produce > perform Action >  Assemble file.m" then Xcode crash Process:               Xcode [6985]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.0 (13247)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13247000000000000~26
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [6985]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-12-08 20:08:52.685 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.6 (16G1108)
Report Version:        12

Comment: Xcode crashing is not good, though it does occasionally :-( You should have been offered the chance to submit a report to Apple, which you should take. After relaunching Xcode the issue usually goes away. If it persists on a particular project hold down the option key then choose `Project > Clean Build Folder` to see if that fixes it. HTH

Comment: @CRD You're explanation is perfectly valid , however `NSObject`'s `mutableCopy` (and `copy` for that matter) methods are not defined as properties. Using `.syntax` for invoking them suggests the opposite.

Comment: @Kamil.S - Agreed, but is it an issue of being "bad" or of "personal taste"? What is the downside?

Comment: @CRD My reasoning is we don't see `NSObject.alloc.init` anywhere in code , because these methods aren't properties even though the compiler won't complain and technically it works. So imho the preferred approach is to stick to original definition. If something is defined as a property then `.syntax` is a way to go otherwise not really.

Comment: @Kamil.S - you will see constructs like `.alloc.init` if you look at Swift code. Swift is one of a number of languages which make no syntactic distinction between property and method/function invocation. We're talking mainly *preferences* here, stick with what you're comfortable with while enjoying the variety of life! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can‘t really see the source code. You could step into it in Xcode‘s debugger though, and see an assembler version of it, which is reasonably readable if you know any platform‘s assembler or are good at guessing abbreviations for english words.