# Allocating two NSMutableArrays while one is an instance variable another is a property

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, allocation

I am new to Objective-C and maybe this question is quite stupid but I'm a little confused about it.

Suppose, I have a class and that class contains two different NSMutableArrays: `library` and `playlists`. Playlists is an `instance variable` while `library` is a property (they are for different purposes). Now, to work with `library` I have  to `alloc init` it (for example, in an initialiser method). But why shouldn't I do the same for `playlists`? 
When I try to do the same for `playlists`, my code stops working, but when I don't do it, it works fine (I can add objects to `playlist`, for example).

**EDIT**
The example when this happens is in the code snippets below. I have two classes `Playlist` and `MusicCollection`. `MusicCollection` has two arrays: `library` (`property`), which contains all songs from all playlists, added to the second array called `playlists` (`instance variable`). The code that doesn't work is this one:

```
-(void)addPlaylist:(Playlist *)thePlaylist {

if ([playlists indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:thePlaylist] != NSNotFound) {
    NSLog(@"ADDED");
    [playlists addObject:thePlaylist];
    [library addObjectsFromArray:thePlaylist.mySongs];
}
}
```

When I have this initialisation method the code above works fine:

```
-(instancetype)initMusicCollectionWithName:(NSString *)nameOfPlaylist {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    self.name = nameOfPlaylist;

    library = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

return self;
}
```

But when I have something like this, it doesn't (it just doesn't add playlists to the `playlists` array).

```
 -(instancetype)initMusicCollectionWithName:(NSString *)nameOfPlaylist {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    self.name = nameOfPlaylist;

    library = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    playlists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

return self;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

As asked, here are the declarations for two arrays:

(`library` array)

```
@interface MusicCollection : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *library;
```

(`playlists` array)

```
@implementation MusicCollection{

NSMutableArray *playlists;
NSRange range;

}
```

Could you explain why this happens, please?

Comment: what you mean with stop working?, can you post your relevant code?

Comment: @ReinierMelian, I have edited the question

Comment: You are going to have to figure this out yourself, or at least narrow it down further and then edit the question to include all relevant details, including the declarations currently omitted. You **must**, somewhere, somehow, allocate your arrays. However an initialised array variable will be `nil`, and messages to `nil` don't error *per se* they just do nothing. Add breakpoints and examine the values in your variables. A good starting point might be your `addObject` line, comparing with and without the allocation in `initMusicCollectionWithName`. HTH

Comment: @CRD, I've added declarations of two arrays, as you asked

Comment: What did the breakpoints reveal? (If you don't know how to use breakpoints now is the time to learn – look up the debugger in the docs.) Also note you are referencing the *property* `library` using just `library` rather than `self.library`. While the code you show suggests the property is automatically created (no user written setter/getter) and so is variable-backed that variable would usually be `_library` unless specified otherwise. *[continued...]*

Comment: *[...continued]* Further the property is declared `copy` which makes no sense as the array will be *immutable*, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690236/how-can-i-look-up-objective-cs-property-synthesize-getter-setter-code/47702760#comment83759234_47702760)

Comment: @CRD, thank you for the link, now I will know that :). About the `library`; I synthesize it, that's why it is`library` and not  `_library`. About using breakpoints: I have noticed that when I `alloc init` `playlists` array, my conditional operator doesn't get called at all, so, I think, the initial implementation of the conditional operator wasn't right. I have to check whether the index of identical object is `NSNotFound` (using `==` operator), and if so, add the playlist to the array. I guess, the reason was that, I was checking the array against NSNotFound without initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
  self.name = nameOfPlaylist;
```

gives  a strong non-nil reference to name string as you declared it as **nonatomic , copy** from **nameOfPlaylist** parameter

so library will work if you pass it like name

```
-(instancetype)initMusicCollectionWithName:(NSString *)nameOfPlaylist library:(NSString*)lib{
     self = [super init];

   if (self) {

     self.name = nameOfPlaylist;

    library = lib;
    }

  return self;
 }
```

wether it's instance variable or property it must be allocated

[image]

and when allocated

[image]

Comment: I have edited my question, where I explain the situation. Could look at it one more time, please?